# 'git pull' command fails

Tags: git, powershell

I'm trying to run a Git pull request from within a PowerShell script.  When I run the code listed below, I'm getting:

```
From http://10.12.10.107:7990/scm/ta/installer
At :line:1 char:2
+ &  <<<< git pull http://myuser:mypassword@10.10.10.10:7990/scm/tainstaller.git > C:\temp\git_out.txt
```

The script is:

```psh
$TestDbScriptLoc = "C:\git\installer\src\dev\resources"
$GitOutput = "C:\temp\git_out.txt"

$PullCommandLine = "git pull    http://myuser:mypassword@10.12.10.107:7990/scm/ta/installer.git"
cd $TestDbScriptLoc
$Result = Invoke-Expression -Command "& $PullCommandLine > $GitOutput" 2> $null
Write-Host (get-Content $GitOutput)
```

What is strange is that when I run the same PowerShell code on Windows 7, it works.  It does NOT work on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Is there any more to that error message? Is git installed on that server? Is it in the `PATH`?